# how to install codeigniter in one folder easyphp?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, easyphp

I'm program a site with codeigniter in root easyphp in my laptop (C:\EasyPHP\www) , Now I transfer it to PC one folder in root easyphp (C:\EasyPHP\www\sample) .
Now it's show me "Object not found!"

this is htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you:

1) really deleted .htaccess from www folder

2) changed base url in CI config